# Is version 11 of Xcode supported by Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin on a Windows PC?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to learn more about Xamarin in my free time.  So far I have created a simple Xamarin Forms app with a UWP target and an Android target.  I want to add an IOS target now.

Therefore I have purchased a MacBook Pro with Mojave 10.14.6.  I have installed Xcode 11 (11A420a) and Visual Studio 2019 version 8.3.1 (I believe) on the Mac.  I have opened Visual Studio 2019 on my Windows PC (version 16.0.3) and successfully paired the Mac.

I then created a Hello World Xamarin Forms app that is targeted by IOS on the Windows PC.  The app runs, however I just see a black screen in the simulator.  I have spent all day Googling this and have got no-where.  Is version 11 of Xcode supported by Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin on a Windows PC? What can I do?

Comment: be sure both machines have the same version of Xamarin installed.  Launch XCode on the Mac and be sure it isn't waiting on any pending downloads or license agreements.  Launch VS on the Mac and verify you can build and launch an iOS app

Comment: Also note that if you have iOS 13 SDK on the Mac you'll need Visual Studio 16.3.2 or greater on your Windows machine.

Comment: @Jason, thanks.  When I run it on macos I see the error: framework not found WatchKit.  It is a helloworld app.  How do I install this watchkit on macos?

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/xamarin-macios/issues/6471

Comment: @Jason, thanks.  How do I "link SDK frameworks only"? I am still trying to work my way around a Mac.

Comment: its the Build tab under the Project Options dialog

Comment: I cannot see a project options in the build menu.  Though I am new to macos.  I have checked and double checked

Comment: @John Mc, thanks.  I have updated to the version of Visual Studio you recommended and it worked.  If you would like to post an answer then I will give credit.  +1.

Comment: Here's a link to Pairing to the Mac: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/windows/connecting-to-mac/  OTH, seeing the release notes on VisualStudio 2019, I've always wondered what support for XCode meant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is version 11 of XCode supported by Visual Studio 2019 and Xamarin on
>   a Windows PC?

Yes, it is suppported.

> I cannot see a project options in the build menu.

Right click the `iOS project`--> `option` --> `iOS build` --> `link behavior`, I will show you the screenshot.

[image]

And [image]

**Update:**

To the original question, update the Visual-Studio to the latest version(16.3.2) will solve it.

Comment: Thanks.  The simulator is not working properly on my Mac (+1 for that).  Are you able to answer my original question about the black screen on the windows PC?

Comment: I assume that I must use Visual Studio 2019 on the PC (and the most current version)?

Comment: @w0051977 You just create a new project and did not change anything, then run the project on the iOS simulator and get a black screen?

Comment: Is there any error logs in the console? Can you add a breakpoint in the Main page to see if it hits? Can you try run a sample porject like [-sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/userinterface-buttondemos/) to see if it works? Not sure what happens on your side.

Comment: Updating to version 16.3.2 has resolved the issue on the Windows PC.  If you add this to your answer (for future readers) then I will accept it.  Also, do you know if XCode 11 works with Visual Studio 2017?

Comment: @w0051977  I have updated the answer.And I think Visual Studio 2017 is not compatible with XCode 11.

Answer (score 1):

If you have iOS 13 SDK on the Mac you'll need Visual Studio 16.3.2 or greater on your Windows machine.